# Is there a way to highlight a question in another site without cross-posting?

Tags: feature-request, questions

I just saw a question: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/8758/can-planets-die-of-old-age that I thought would fit better in Earth Science that in it's current location (Word Building?!). I don't want to cross-post, but it would be nice to highlight the question (and answers) in our site. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer this from the perspective of a Worldbuilding user.

One of the good things about the site is that scientific and mathematical answers are welcome (to questions tagged [science-based](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) or [reality-check](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check)). I take full advantage of this, and to my knowledge, I've used LaTeX much more in my answers than anyone else there.

We do have a decent amount of users from other science sites - such as myself - and some actual experts. This ensures that there a flow of scientific knowledge, and that most answers are accurate and backed up with references if possible.

One of the things I *dislike* about the site is that the definition of a "scientific answer" is open to debate. I don't mean to demean any users or answers there - I've seen a lot of really, really, *really* good scientific answers there. The problem is, most of these answers aren't as rigorous as answers on a science site. I can flip to a random answer on Earth Science and likely find a more complete scientific analysis than on an equivalent question on Worldbuilding.

There's something to take into account, though. Answers on Worldbuilding using the tags I mentioned before aren't necessarily looking for an extraordinarily in-depth answer. The askers want to know if their setup is plausible, feasible, and realistic. I generally go out of my way to answer each of these questions (that I do answer) as I would on, say Astronomy. But that's often unnecessary, and the math might scare some people off.

The point is this: You can ask a similar question to eon on Worldbuilding here and get drastically different but equally accurate answers. Do I condone cross-posting? No. But unless I - or one of the other hard-science answerers - have answered the question on Worldbuilding, you're likely to get a different response here. So I'd say you can ask a similar question.

In this case, though, I think the answers on Worldbuilding are fine.